# How to change ResourceAuthorizationContext from Thinktecture.IdentityModel ResourceAuthorizationManager and Web Api 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, thinktecture-ident-model, thinktecture

I am creating a Web Api 2 application using `Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ResourceAuthorization` , I was taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/e6cf193dbffbe1dc3a15848106807983ec503c22/source/Owin.ResourceAuthorization.WebApi) and I realized I wanted to change the properties available on my `ResourceAuthorizationContext` , I would like to create a custom `Context` and use it for everything related to `ResourceAuthorization`. That way I could add custom properties to be available for my `CheckAccessAsync` method.

My goal is to have something like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationManager : ResourceAuthorizationManager
{
    public override Task<bool> CheckAccessAsync(CustomResourceAuthorizationContext context)
    {
        // Access my custom properties coming directly from the context
    }
}
```

So I could use a CustomAttribute like this:

```
[CustomResourceAuthorize("CustomValue", "MoreCustomValues")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
}
```

I couldn't figure out a way to customize the `Context`, like I do with the `ResourceAuthorizationManager`, at the startup.
The problem seems to be [these extension methods](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/blob/e6cf193dbffbe1dc3a15848106807983ec503c22/source/Owin.ResourceAuthorization.WebApi/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs), they reference the `ResourceAuthorizationContext` class directly.

Am I missing something or you really can't do this?